# Lucene.Net and Geosearch - is it outthere somewhere?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I've found an interesting article about Lucene and geosearching:

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/02/spatial-search-with-lucene.html

Is there an equivilant .NET implementation out there that I have been unable to find or do I have to rework the Java-code in his example to fit in the .NET Framework?

Comment: How did you get on with geosearching using Lucene.net? I'm after the same requirement myself.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this article, as well.  I do not see a .NET-specific in my Googling, so I am planning on probably porting this code when the need arises, as well.  Right now, I am just getting my feet wet with Lucene.NET and have not gotten to the point that I am comfortable enough with it to start extending it, yet.

The code in the article appears to be a derived example of the conceptual geo-distance functionality outlined in Lucene In Action.  Although the book is based on the Java product, it is a great read.  The samples port easily and it is full of information.

Answer (score 1):

in the latest lucene.net contrib folder there is spatial contribution to perform geosearch see

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_1/contrib/Spatial.Net/

Answer (score 0):

With Lucene.NET 3.0.3, soon to be released, there is a brand new spatial contrib. See:

http://www.code972.com/blog/2012/05/the-future-of-geo-spatial-searches-with-lucene/

Answer (score 0):

There is worked example at https://www.leapinggorilla.com/Blog/Read/1010/spatial-search-in-lucenenet---worked-example

Regards

Ismail